# Android - NoClassDefFoundError for an Inner Class

Tags: android, inner-classes

I found a lot of information regarding the NoClassDefFoundError on external jars, but I am getting this error on an inner class in my main activity: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.mysite.ezbudget.EZbudget$ConfirmResetFragment. Here is the relevant code:

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
void showDialog() {
     DialogFragment newFragment = ConfirmResetFragment.newInstance(0);
     newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}


@TargetApi(11)
    public static class ConfirmResetFragment extends DialogFragment {

        public static  ConfirmResetFragment newInstance(int title) {
            ConfirmResetFragment frag = new ConfirmResetFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("test", title);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
            }
.......
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint as to what might be going on? I expect it is a versioning issue, but the error message is a bit confusing. Thanks.

Comment: on any target before 11, your class is not included, as it uses fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [The Compatibility Package](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/) to have support of fragments lower than api level 11.